# How to calculate separation when velocities are at some angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

### original problem

Two ships A And B originally at a distance $d$ from each other depart at the same time from a straight coastline. Ship Moves along a straight line perpendicular to the shore while ship B constantly heads for ship A having at each moment the same speed as the latter. After a sufficiently great interval of time the second ship will obviously follow the first one at a certain distance. Find the distance.

### my approach

I used the method of relative velocity where component of velocity of one object is increasing the separation and other decreasing the separation [image]

but I'm able to proceed with the integral thing . Any help

Comment: Use mathJax for mathematics writing.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi how to

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/687460

Comment: @Saniya - put equations between dollar signs `$...$` for inline expressions such as $1+x^2$ and double dollar signs `$$...$$` for paragraph style expressions like the following $$y = \int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x $$ also right click on an expression and select `show math as/Tex commands` to look at the syntax.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou scan you guide  a bit more in chat

Answer (score 1):

You need the euclidian distance between the two ships.

[image: fig]

If ship **A** is at $x_A$ from the shoreline, and ship **B** is at $(x_B,y_B)$ relative to the initial position of **A** then the distance between them is defined as

$$ h = \sqrt{ (x_A-x_B)^2 + y_B^2 } $$

All you have to do is describe $x_A$ and $(x_B,y_B)$ as a function of time, and take the limit of $h$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. You will also need that at time zero ship **B** is a distance $d$ vertically from **A**, or $(x_B,y_B)|_{t=0} = (0,d) $.

Comment: I'm guessing hat ship B will never be exactly behind ship A.

Comment: @R.W.Bird it's an ideal case that they meet at infinity

Comment: @John alexion I suppose that xa can be determined as vt but for writing cooddiantes of b I'll have to break down the components of velocity in x and y direction?

Comment: That is a different question. You asked about separation at first. Now you are asking me to solve your problem, which is not allowed on this site. How you establish the path of **B** is the next question.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou ur answer seems incomplete as I'm not able to comprehend the last part

Comment: What is $v_x$ for **B**? Find that and integrate it to get $x_B$.

Comment: Let's chat @JohnAlexiou I want to know detailed answer

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I know how **I** would try to solve this.

Comment: https://irodovphysicssolutionrks.blogspot.com/2012/06/113.html?m=1 exactly same problem here solution

Answer (score 0):

This problem has several inter-related variables. I went looking for equations that would tie them together. I'm assuming that ship A starts at x = 0 and moves along the x axis at speed v.  Ship B starts at x = 0 and y = d and moves toward ship A at speed v. Measured from ship A to ship B, distance, R, forms an angle, θ, with the x direction.  For ship B: $v_x$ = v cos(θ) and $v_y$ = - v sin(θ).  Also, vt – x = R cos(θ)  and y = R sin(θ) giving dx/dt = v + R sin(θ) dθ/dt – cos(θ) dR/dt and dy/dt = R cos(θ) dθ/dt + sin(θ) dR/dt.  Equating the two expressions for $v_x$ gives equation (1). Doing the same for $v_y$ gives equation (2).  Dividing each by the sine or cosine lets dR/dt stand alone.
Then subtracting (1) from (2) yields:  – v/cos(θ) = R(dθ/dt)[(cos(θ)/sin(θ)) + (sin(θ)/cos(θ)].
With a common denominator, this reduces to: - v sin(θ) = R(dθ/dt). Using this to replace the -v sin(θ) in equation (2) gives: R(dθ/dt) = R(dθ/dt) cos(θ) + sin(θ)(dR/dt)  take out the dt and you have:  dR/R = [(1- cos(θ))/sin(θ)] dθ.  Integrating both sides of this equation from start to finish
gives the ratio of $R_{final}$ over d.  (I used a numeric integrator for the right side which worked in one direction, but not the other.) I also set up a numeric simulation for this situation on a spreadsheet and its results agree with this one with several sets of input numbers. The fact that the ratio is a simple fraction and is independent of the starting numbers suggest that there should be a simpler way to approach this problem.

Comment: Would be really comprehendable if you use mathjax

Comment: Try working it through, step by step.  The last equation is the one that gives a final answer.